# How to get rid of zeros in the section numbering in LATEX report document class?

Tags: numbers, report, latex, sections

So I'm writing a report using Latex and the document class I am using is report:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

But for some reason the section numbering is written so that it is preceded with "0.", for example it looks like:

```
0.1 Introduction

0.2 Theory

0.3 Experimental Method
```

and so on.

Can somebody help me get rid of those zeros so that it appears how it is supposed to be?

Comment: A report requires that you use `\chapter` as first level. If you don't need chapters you possibly use the article class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`report` assumes you'll be using `\chapter`s as your main sectional unit. As such, all sectional units are marked "relative" to the `\chapter` counter. Specifically, `\section` counters are set using `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`. Either use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

to remove any reference of `\chapter`s, or add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

to your document preamble.

The former would have greater impact on the actual output, as the setting of a `\title` and possibly the layout *may* be different. The latter would just remove the `\chapter` counter from being printed with every `\section` (and lower-level section unit).